# How to calculate 'Count per user' value in Firebase Events

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics

I have a question abut Firebase Events.
Firebase Events view shows 'Event count', 'Users' and 'Count per user'. (Ref. below screenshot link)
I think that 'Count per user' is calculated by 'Event Count' / 'Users' but 'Count per user' value is different from I calculated.
I there anyone know how this value calculated?
Is it a Firebase's bug?

[image: Example of Firebase Events view I explained]